# Why is the data modal didnt popout when i clicked on the ADD button?

Tags: modal-dialog, laravel-8

im new at using laravel 8, im following this tutorial tu create an ADD button with the modal but seems like the difference in version of laravel cause the problem where nothing happenned when i clicked on the ADD button.  i'm following this video tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rQ4m6xe5wGM&list=PLRheCL1cXHrvJvoJ68PXdJr5tr5Aob2-c&index=9

this is the  code from the getbootstrap that i copied from the website. the step is just the same as the tutorial but mine doesnt popout

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal" data-bs-whatever="@getbootstrap">Open modal for @getbootstrap</button>

<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">New message</h5>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form>
          <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Recipient:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="recipient-name">
          </div>
          <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="message-text" class="col-form-label">Message:</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" id="message-text"></textarea>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Send message</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to popup a bootstrap modal when clicking a button in bootstrap version 4
use `data-target` attribute like this `data-target="#exampleModal"` pass an id with a hashtag .then you can make a popup that modal when button click pass that id in modal class id attribute id="exampleModal"

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```